# Cinema Booking Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, system

I am creating a cinema application in Ruby on Rails where users can log in and view movies and the times and dates they're being shown. What I want to do is create a booking system so that a user, e.g. "Joe Bloggs", can select a film, e.g. "Jaws", and a seat in its 20:00 showing at the cinema. Has anyone got some suggestions for how I can create this?

I already have a lot of the tables and entities needed, but what I'm asking is how to code this into the application? Is there a gem that I could use?

Comment: This is a good tutorial for movie ticket booking, hope it helps http://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-5-building-a-solid-data-model/

Comment: Sit down with a pencil and paper and draw out all your real life entities and how they relate to each other, eg Cinema, Screen, Seat, Film, Showing, Booking

Comment: Yeah I've done that, made a basic ERD for it, just wondered if there's a gem to use for bookings

Comment: ah - you should have said that earlier, i just wasted my time drawing up a schema for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is how i would start off trying to logically represent the relationships between entities.  Real life may be more complicated but this is a good start i think.  From these relationships you can determine the tables and fields required.  Note that i've mainly just listed the relationship fields, there would probably be lots of other fields you might want to store, eg whether a cinema or particular screen has wheelchair access etc.

```
Cinema #eg Odeon, West Street, Brighton
  has_many :screens
  #fields - name, address

Screen #eg Screen 1, Screen 2 etc
  belongs_to :cinema
  has_many :seats
  #fields - name

Seat #A1, A2 etc
  belongs_to :screen
  has_many :bookings
  #fields - number, eg "A2"

Film #eg Jaws
  has_many :showings
  #fields - name, length, rating, etc

Showing #Eg Jaws in screen 2 of odeon west street brighton at 9pm on 10/3/2015
  belongs_to :screen
  belongs_to :film
  has_many :bookings
  #fields: screening_time (datetime)

User #eg Joe Bloggs
  has_many :bookings
  #fields - name, address etc  

Booking #eg Joe Bloggs' reservation for seat A2 for Jaws in screen 2 of odeon west street brighton at 9pm on 10/3/2015
  belongs_to :showing
  belongs_to :seat
  belongs_to :user
```

Comment: I do not understand why do we need to have Seat has many bookings..? Can you please tell me a real time example.? Did you mean, One seat can be booked my many people.? or one seat can be attempted to book by many people.? This might be a silly question, but i really dont understand..

Comment: Think of an actual seat in a cinema.  How many people do you think sit on that seat in a given year?  Each of those is a booking.

Comment: Oh yeah I got it. I dint think of that., I thought a seat can be booked by multiple people for a single show. Thanks a lot Max. :) :) :)